# How to generate api and pages for all days in a year - React/Next JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an api that can accept all days of a year and return information for all days.

```
https://api.mywebsite.org/data/all/${month}/${day}
```

Right now, I have a page called `https://mywebsite.org/today` which returns info for today.
My goal is to make the page available for all days of the year. For example Feb 28 would be:

```
https://mywebsite.org/today/feb/28
```

will pass 02 (month) and 28(day) to the api.

My routes are very simple. For Example for users, my route looks like below but users are stored in a database. I am not guessing or making up values like I want to do for dates.

```
/user/[userId]/index.js
```

I can create a route called /today/[date]/index.js but **how to create this for all days of the year?**

I would like users to be able to just enter any month/day.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to use is called **Dynamic Routes** (you can read more about [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes))

First of all you need to name the file like this `pages/[...params].js`
That will match a set of routes like:

```
 1. /feb
 2. /feb/23
 3. /a/b/c
```

Don't forget to validate the parameters (I suppose third case should redirect to 404)

You can use **useRouter** hook to get the parameters from the URL:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const Component = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { params} = router.query // this will return an array of query parameters

  // parameters validation here

  return <></>
}

export default Component
```